# Identify a comic where The Stranger's mid-section disappears

Tags: story-identification, marvel, thor-marvel

1. It's probably a 1980's or 1970's comic
2. I'm near positive The Stranger was fighting Thor
3. Mjolnir passes through The Stranger's midsection as it vanishes during combat

Can someone identify this marvel comic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comic you are looking for is [*Thor Vol 1* #178](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_178) "Death is a Stranger", published in July 1970.

In this comic, Thor and The Stranger end up fighting, and during the course of that fight Thor throws Mjölnir through The Stranger's midsection.

Here's a picture of that exact moment:

[image]

Comment: Om my God! That's it!! Thanks!!